# Using Enums in Qt slots

Tags: qt, enums, slots

In the class QCustomPlot have enums that I want to use in the constructor of the QWidget class, which uses class QCustomPlot.

```
#include "qcustomplot.h"

SignalViewerDialog::SignalViewerDialog(QVector<double> x_1,
                                       QVector<double> y_1,
                                       QCPScatterStyle::ScatterProperty ScatterProp,
                                       QCPScatterStyle::ScatterShape ScatterShp,
                                       QCPGraph::LineStyle LineSt,
                                       QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
```

ERROR

> /Users/konstantin/Desktop/SVMGLEP/signalviewerdialog.cpp:72: ошибка: reference to type 'const QCPScatterStyle' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'QCPScatterStyle::ScatterProperty'
>           ui.widgetGraph->graph()->setScatterStyle(ScatterProp);
>                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Has the proposed answer solved the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to with the problem of passing enums in signal-slot connection, where you need to register the enum within the Qt metatype system. This is a simple type mismatch in plain C++.

To quote the [reference](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPScatterStyle.html):

> **Specifying a scatter style**
>
> You can set all these configurations either by calling the respective
>   functions on an instance:
>
> ```
> QCPScatterStyle myScatter;  
> myScatter.setShape(QCPScatterStyle::ssCircle);  
> myScatter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));   myScatter.setBrush(Qt::white);  
> myScatter.setSize(5);  
> customPlot->graph(0)->setScatterStyle(myScatter);
> ```
>
> Or you can use one of the various constructors that take different parameter
>   combinations, making it easy to specify a scatter style in a single
>   call, like so:
>
> ```
> customPlot->graph(0)->setScatterStyle(
>    QCPScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssCircle, Qt::blue, Qt::white, 5)
> );
> ```

You are passing an enum of type `QCPScatterStyle::ScatterProperty` in place of an object of class `QCPScatterStyle`.

Edit 1: Hence, you need to use

```
ui.widgetGraph->graph()->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle(ScatterProp));
```

Edit 2: Also I'd like to note that you're using `CamelCase` for the names of the function parameters of type `enum`. Maybe you're doing that because they are enums, but I'd advise againt doing that, since later on in the code they appear to be actual enum values, not variable names.